# SDK Error Compiling error

Tags: iphone, cocoa, xcode

Hi Guys i'm using this QR code scanner SDK from http://shopsavvy.mobi/sdk/.

i did everything that is shown is the demo apps and try to do it in my own app and encounter this whole chunk of error.

"__ZNSs6appendERKSs", referenced from:

```
  __ZN5zxing4oned13Code128Reader9decodeRowEiNS_3RefINS_8BitArrayEEE in libScannerKit.a(Code128Reader.o)


  __ZN5zxing4oned10UPCEReader17convertUPCEtoUPCAESs in libScannerKit.a(UPCEReader.o)


  __ZN5zxing4oned10UPCEReader17convertUPCEtoUPCAESs in libScannerKit.a(UPCEReader.o)

  __ZSt24__uninitialized_copy_auxIPN5zxing3RefINS0_10datamatrix7VersionEEES5_ET0_T_S7_S6_St12__false_type in libScannerKit.a(Version-52918D8C2E078B47.o)


  __ZNSt6vectorIN5zxing3RefINS0_10datamatrix7VersionEEESaIS4_EE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS4_S6_EERKS4_ in libScannerKit.a(Version-52918D8C2E078B47.o)


  __ZSt24__uninitialized_copy_auxIPN5zxing3RefINS0_6qrcode8DataMaskEEES5_ET0_T_S7_S6_St12__false_type in libScannerKit.a(DataMask.o)
 __ZNSt6vectorIN5zxing3RefINS0_6qrcode8DataMaskEEESaIS4_EE13_M_insert_auxEN9__gnu_cxx17__normal_iteratorIPS4_S6_EERKS4_ in libScannerKit.a(DataMask.o)
```

ld: symbol(s) not found

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

thanks in advances for helping :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you are missing on a required framework. Check the sdk dependencies and add the required frameworks in your project.

Answer (score 1):

You are not linking against the C++ library.
You can tell by using *c++filt* to de-mangle your missing symbol:

```
cristi:~ diciu$ echo __ZNSs6appendERKSs | c++filt
std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::append(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)

cristi:~ diciu$ nm /usr/lib/libstdc++.6.dylib  | grep __ZNSs6appendERKSs
00030f1e T __ZNSs6appendERKSs
00030e66 T __ZNSs6appendERKSsmm
```

If you're writing Objective-C code, saving your file with the extension ".mm" instead of ".m" may help.